# Three floated elements with one that shrinks to available space

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly confident this is one of those things that has been discussed endlessly out there in the internet, but I can't find a solution.

I need to float 2 divs on the same line as a paragraph.  Both of the divs have variable width and I need the paragraph to shrink into the available space and wrap its contents so that none of the elements themselves wrap off the line.

I've set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDRXf/)

HTML here:

```
<div class="icon"></div>
<p>This is a really long line of text that will need to wrap</p>
<div class="count"></div>
```

CSS here:

```
.icon {float:left; width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#4d4d4d; margin-right:10px}
p {margin:0; overflow:auto; display:inline-block}
.count {float:right; width:250px; height:50px; background-color:#ff0000; margin-left:10px}
```

I know that I can use Javascript to achieve this, but I'd much rather find a pure CSS solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The code in your question is different from the code in your fiddle.

Comment: something like this - width percentage widths and inline-blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/LTuGW/

Comment: Sorry - I pasted the wrong fiddle URL - I've edited the question to correct the link

Answer (score 0):

Floats do not shrink or expand to fit the available space. A floated item always uses the required space of any children.

That is [what flexbox was invented for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

```
.flex-column-container {
    flex: 1 auto 1;
}
```

Alternatively you could [use a table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle if this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/dEwuU/

here is HTML

```
   <div class="main">
    <div class="w_200"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="w_200"></div>
</div>
```

here is css

```
body,div{ 
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.main {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  min-width:404px;
  background:black;
  float:left;
}
.w_200 {
  width:200px;
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
.middle {
  height:100px;
  background:red; 
  float:left;
  width: 49.2%;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 404px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 404px);
  width: calc(100% - 404px);
  margin:0px 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately none of the elements will have known widths.  Although I've included them in the fiddle, they will have variable widths as I've stated in the question.  So the paragraph needs to shrink to fit whatever space is left.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  If I change the paragraph to display:block instead of inline-block and change the order of the elements so that the paragraph is the last in the markup it works perfectly.